# Installed extension failed in remote

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

When I try to install extension in remote of VS Code, I always get error:

> [error] Failed to install extension: ms-vscode.cpptools connect ETIMEDOUT 13.107.6.175:443

I don't know why I will connect to this IP.

I've already tried to configure proxy in my remote, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Just put that ip address in the address bar of your browser to see the cause of this problem.  Try again later.

Comment: I'm hitting this issue right now (2020-04-01); the IP as an https address returns:
Our services aren't available right now
We're working to restore all services as soon as possible. Please check back soon.